# Fetching data from Api in Reactjs using Axios

Tags: reactjs, api

I'm trying to fetch data from this api https://randomuser.me/api/?results=25
with this code

```
function Users() {
 const [Users, setUsers] = useState([])
    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get('https://randomuser.me/api/?results=25')
        .then(Response=>{
            if(Response.data){
                alert("FOund")
                setUsers([Response.data])
                

            }else{
                alert("not found")
            }
        })
    }, [])
    const displaylist = Users.map((User,index)=>{
        return(
        <h3>{User.gender}</h3>
        )
    })
    
    return (
        <div>
            {displaylist}
        </div>
    )
}

export default Users
```

But nothing is showing up and console is giving this error:
Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.

Check the render method of `Users`. See https://reactjs.org/link/warning-keys for more information.
at h3
at Users (http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:627:83)
at div
at App

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[image]

The usage of Json result is wrong , `

```
  if (Response.result) {
    alert("FOund");
    setUsers(Response.result);
  } else {
    alert("not found");
  }`
```

Answer (score 1):

When you map through an array React needs a unique key, something like a User.id; in this case you could use the index as well. I changed your function a little bit like this:

```
function Users() {
  const [Users, setUsers] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get("https://randomuser.me/api/?results=25").then((Response) => {
      if (Response.data) {
        alert("FOund");
        setUsers(Response.data.results);
      } else {
        alert("not found");
      }
    }).catch(error => console.log(error));
  }, []);
  const displaylist = Users.map((User, index) => {
    return <h3 key={index}>{User.gender}</h3>;
  });

  return <div>{displaylist}</div>;
}

export default Users;
```